# How to update a particular line in a file?

Tags: c++, file

I have a file that's got a few unnecessary characters at the end of the second line. How to edit a line from the file and write it back to the same line without replacing the whole file?

Comment: Why are you doing this with C++?

Comment: look at random file access : http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/137-random-file-io/

Answer (score 0):

> I'll probably have to write the whole file again

Not quite the whole file. You only need to re-write the part that comes after the removed characters.

> but how do I edit the a line from the file and write it back to the same line?

- Find the position `a` of the first character that you want to remove.
- Find the position `b` of the the first character that you don't want to remove, which is the next newline character in this case.
- Read the rest of the file, starting from `b`.
- Write the content that you have read, starting from the position `a`.